# Facebook Crash After Login second time

Tags: cordova, ionic3, facebook-login

I have an issue regarding facebook login in ionic. I can logged in successfull for first time. As i logout from facebook using app and try to login again, My application crashes with Nullpointer exception. The image of the issue is as below:-

[image]

I have seen similar issue on below links and tried possible solutions for the same.
https://github.com/jeduan/cordova-plugin-facebook4/pull/642

https://github.com/jeduan/cordova-plugin-facebook4/issues/568

The version of ionic cordova Facebook plugin I am using is 4.11.0.

The code I have used to implement the functionality is as below:-

```
this.fb.login(['email', 'public_profile']).then((res:FacebookLoginResponse)=>{
              this.fb.api('me?fields=id,name,email,first_name,picture.width(720).height(720).as(picture_large)', ['email', 'public_profile']).then(profile => {
                this.userData = {email: profile['email'], first_name: profile['first_name'], picture: profile['picture_large']['data']['url'], username: profile['name']}
                  if(res.status === "connected") {
                    this.isLoggedIn = true;
                    this.socialLogin(this.userData.email,"facebook",this.userData.first_name);
                  }else{
                    this.isLoggedIn = false;
                  }
              });
            }).catch(e => console.log('Error logging into Facebook', e));
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I have the same error, still no solution found.